# Datagrid button column how to bind a function to a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datagrid

Currently i have a datagrid view that displays names in the 1st columnnd in the 2nd column delete buttons.

This datagrid view already has bind data to a function so it can displays the names that are withint a xml file (first column is a hyperlink column).

But next i want to be able to delete the xml values that are in the first column.
(by clicking on the delete button on the second column of it)

```
<name></name>
```

But how do i exactly bind a (delete) function to these buttons?

```
name1    btnDelete
name2    btnDelete
etc...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For datagrid you have handle the ondeletecommand event, see below.

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dg" ondeletecommand="dg_DeleteCommand">
```

then define the event handler in your code behind .. see below.

```
protected void dg_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

the DataGridCommandEventArgs has all the properties you'll need to check including **e.CommandName** etc

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about datagrid but in gridView I use

set button's command name and use GridView's RowCommand Event.

```
if(e.commandName == "delete")
//ur code;
```

Template field

for default delete of GridView use

girdViewRowDeleting

Hope it will help..

Comment: Hello, but how do i get this e.commandName i seem to be unable to acces that. I already have placed the Command Name on delete in my aspx file but how to acces this in aspx.cs? Thanks

Comment: you have to use the event of data grid
    protected void MyGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    // now you can use e and e.CommandName
    }